# Creating a summary table (how to process data through a dynamic for loop for specific column and row)

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty new to macros vba, so it's kinda multiple questions in one
What I'm trying to create is a summary. Let's say I have a huge data table in 
excel, for clearness sake here's an excerpt (only for illsutration, actual table is much larger)

```
Chase_list

  A (Name)         B (Due)    C (Queries)     D (Comment)      
  Customer 1       50 464     20 000          Long-time debtor
  Customer 2        3 159     0               Resent invoice
  Customer 1       15 000     0               
  Customer 4       18 000     3 200           Promised payment
```

So let's say I got this set of data, **now I want to create a function that will go through every cell in the table and if the sum of the due and queries (column B and C) is greater than 20 000 to write the company into a summary table (on a new worksheet)**

Here's what I have so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim chase_list As Worksheet
  Dim summary_list As Worksheet
  Dim due As Range
  Dim query As Range
  Set chase_list = Sheets("Chase_list") ' the name of my data worksheet in example
  Set summary_list = Sheets("Summary_list") ' the name the sheet i want to output data to

  ' now i need to create a function that will add the query and due column together
  Dim current_row_sum As Range

  'Let's go through every due invoice and query
  For Each due In chase_list.UsedRange.Columns("B")
    For Each query In chase_list.UsedRange.Columns("C")
        current_row_sum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(due, query)
        If (current_row_sum >= 20000) Then
            ' now i somehow need to create a loop that will basically add a new line every time a value is added, but I do not know how
            ' I know I could set it through Range("").Value = field, issue is, I don;t want to put it in a stationary cell, but on new line for each new value
        End If
    Next query
   Next due


End Sub
```

There are probably more issues with the code, given I'm new to vba, albeit I have some coding experience

Expected output

```
Summary_list

  A (Name)         B (Total)   C (Comment)        
  Customer 1       70 464      Long-time Debtor               
  Customer 4       21 200      Promised Payment
```

I know it's not really a specific answer, sorry for that, but it's kind of difficult to split this into parts. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like the following, this assumes you already have a second sheet for your summary:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set your worksheet, change as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find the last row with data on column A

For i = 2 To LastRow
'loop from row 2 to last
    If ws.Cells(i, 2) + ws.Cells(i, 3) > 20000 Then 'if Column 2 (ie B) + Column 3 (ie C) > 20000 then
        ResultFreeRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the next free row on Result Sheet
        ws.Rows(i).Copy wsResult.Rows(ResultFreeRow) 'copy row to next free row
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the help. Needed small fine-tuning, to fit my intended purpose but served as a great example :)

Much more straightforward than my attempt at dynamic dual looping